# Jump Point Search final path

Tags: path-finding

I have been studying the Jump Point Search(JPS) path-finding algorithm recently but I do not fully understand how the final path is chosen.

In A* all the parent nodes are in the closed list and after the goal becomes a parent it tracks back through the closed list. The path will not be calculated until the goal node becomes a parent node in the closed list which will then track back through the parent nodes in the closed list that it is related to.

So how does JPS achieve this if it jumps over most of the nodes in the grid. A* works back through each node it has calculated but JPS can't do this can it?

JPS doesn't have a list of parent nodes in the closed list so does it just connect the path from one node to another ie. it draws a line from one node to another node which is five nodes away rather than a line from one node to another?

I have read all of Harabor's and Grastien's papers on the subject so please do not give me links as I do not understand the way they have explained it :)

If you can explain this to me well then you have my many thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

What you need to keep in mind is that JPS is still A*. The only difference is that instead of always expanding all the neighbors of the current node, it only considers a subset of them.
As such, you stil need to keep track of the parents of jump nodes. Here you have to think of a parent as the node you have to go through to reach the current node. In A*, this will always be an adjacent node. In JPS this will often be a node many steps ahead of you. These steps, however, will always be along one specific movement vector. To find the'path' between the node and its parent you just have to keep taking steps from one to the other according to the normalized movement vector between them.

For example you have a node (5,3) with parent (2,0). node - parent gives you (3,3), which normalized gives you the step (1,1). In this case, taking 3 diagonal steps along (1,1), or in other words to positive x and positive y, brings you from parent to node.